# Angular changing dataset without $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects like this

```
UserList = [
{name:'user1',id:1,data:{}},
{name:'user4',id:4,data:{}},
{name:'user7',id:7,data:{}}
]
```

And html select like this

```
<select ng-model="data.selectedUser">

    <option ng-repeat="item in data.items" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>

</select>

<p>{{data.userPhone}}</p>
```

Inside my controller I use

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.selectedUser = 0;
$scope.data.items = UserListModel.items;
$scope.data.userPhone = UserListModel.items[$scope.data.selectedUser].phone;
```

Is there a way to update selected user phone on selectedUser change without using $watch and stuffing the "$scope.data.userPhone" inside it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have a data like this:

```
  $scope.data = {};
  //set the data
  $scope.data= [{
    id: 1,
    name: "cyril",
    phone: "1234567"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "josh",
    phone: "1237"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "sim",
    phone: "4567"
  }];
  //selected hold the object that is selected in the selectbox.
  $scope.selected = $scope.data[0];
```

Your html will look like this below so now when you select the new user from the list it will be updated in the model `selectedItem`, the `selectedItem` has the *phone number* in it *(so you dont need a watch to update phone number seperately as you doing)*.

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>selected item is : {{selectedItem}}</p>

    <p> name of selected item is : {{selectedItem.name}} </p>

    <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items track by item.id"></select>

  </body>
```

working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/l5qmkw)

Comment: Yep, totally forgot to use ng-options there. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to have

```
$scope.data.userPhone = function () { 
    return UserListModel.items[$scope.data.selectedUser].phone;
}
```

This would mean though that you'd have to update any bindings to use `data.userPhone()` instead.

This might be worse than using a watch though, as the function would get called during every digest.

Without knowing how `selectedUser` gets updated it's difficult to suggest a best way as, with most things, it depends.